# can't find app on market

Tags: android, manifest, tablet

I installed manually the apk of my app on Asus Transform and it works fine, I deployed it on the market but i can't find it (I can find it with my Samsung Galaxy Ace), should I set something on my manifest?
Thanks

EDIT
manifest.xml

```
            <activity
                android:name="Splash"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>                         

            <activity
                android:name=".PoiDetail"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>    

            <activity
                android:name=".FinishWigo"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>    


            <activity
                android:name=".SyncMap"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>                            

            <activity 
                android:name=".mioTTS"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".InvioMessaggio"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".AzioniPoi"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".listaRicerca"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".AdvancedPreferences"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@drawable/resstyle"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".Sync"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name="PoiShow"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity> 


            <activity
                android:name="com.mitcom.wigoCremona.wigo"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    <uses-permission 
            android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Most likely it has something to do with the hardware configuration of your phone. It can also be because your application specifies a language different from the one registered for your phone.
It would help if you show us your manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you are allowing the permission CALL_PHONE.  If I'm not mistaken the Transform can't make a phone call.  As a result the app is likely be filtered out of the market based on that.

Here's a quote from the page on developers.android.com

> Each time you upload an application to the Android Market Publisher Site,
>   Android Market scans the application's
>   manifest file. It looks for
>   `<uses-feature>` elements and evaluates
>   them in combination with other
>   elements, in some cases, such as
>   `<uses-sdk>` and `<uses-permission>`
>   elements. After establishing the
>   application's set of required
>   features, it stores that list
>   internally as metadata associated with
>   the application .apk and the
>   application version.
>
> When a user searches or browses for
>   applications using the Android Market
>   application, the service compares the
>   features needed by each application
>   with the features available on the
>   user's device. If all of an
>   application's required features are
>   present on the device, Android Market
>   allows the user to see the application
>   and potentially download it. If any
>   required feature is not supported by
>   the device, Android Market filters the
>   application so that it is not visible
>   to the user and not available for
>   download.

Here's a link to the page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Hope this helps you out.

Edit - Sorry this duplicates Nanne's answer was typing as they were posting.

Answer (score 1):

CHeck out the permissions: you are asking for some things that the transform might not have (for instance: `ACCESS_GPS`, `CALL_PHONE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

If the device doesn't support one of these (doesn't have a simcard, doesn't support GPS, etc), then you probably can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

My application could work dynamically: in case the phone functionality was not available it would not try to use the phone functionality when user would press on any phone number inside of my application. In other case it would try using phone application to proceed to the call. Would that be possible? (i would then remove the feature from manifest).