# My application is not listed for tablets

Tags: android, manifest, tablet

I have uploaded to play.google.com a new application:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=development.nk.anguide

The problem is that i can not install this application in a tablet.
At optimization tips there is the following message:
"Your APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Any required hardware features are normally available on tablets."

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="development.nk.anguide"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.01" >

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="development.nk.anguide.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="development.nk.anguide.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--  ΝΟΜΙΖΩ ΔΕΝ ΧΡΕΙΑΖΟΝΤΑΙ ΤΑ 2 ΠΑΡΑΚΑΤΩ... -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_144_144"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="development.nk.anguide.xxxxxxxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DetailForm"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapAllActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".EditPreferences"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Categories"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SubCategory"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoriesExpandableList"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value=".......my API key .............." />
    </application>
```

The quite odd think is that i can install my app in my tablet through usb cable and run it normaly from eclipse...

So what should i change to be able for downloading from tablets?

Thank you in advance for reading my problem..

Comment: In case you miss it, now your app is visible and compatible with my tablets (Galaxy Tab 2 and Asus Transformer Pad TF300T). Don't forget to accept an answer ;-) !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
<!--  ΝΟΜΙΖΩ ΔΕΝ ΧΡΕΙΑΖΟΝΤΑΙ ΤΑ 2 ΠΑΡΑΚΑΤΩ... -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Try this instead:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

This question was already asked, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882955/android-permission-call-phone-for-tablets) for more info. Also if you are targeting tablet and phones, you don't need to write this on your code, IMHO:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I don't use this on my applications.

Comment: So you mean, to support tablets and smartphones you shouldn't use `supports-screens` but the telephony `uses-feature`? What sense makes this?

Comment: @N.K., removing these 2 permissions replacing them by the `uses-feature` tag will make your app crash!

Comment: I removed these 2 permissions and my app did not crash! Now i uploaded at play.google.com the new version and i will wait. At meantime the Optimization tip was vanished ! So i am in a good way.. Just waiting..

Comment: @N.K., if it doesn't crash that's because you don't need them :)

Comment: @yugidroid no, i didn't mensioned nothing in what you say in first comment, I only suggest to delete supports-screens in order to target every type of device. N.K. will sentence if I'm right or not :-) .

Answer (score 1):

You can install any app into any device (smartphone/ tablet) using USB cable from eclipse as long as you define correctly the application's target SDK to work with them.

Although the store won't recognize it unless you use some kind of "filters" do to that.

To resolve your issue add the `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` to the `supports-screens` tag.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

The 600 (dp units) means all devices must have, at least, 600dp minimum usable area of wide. This is the same as 7'' screens or higher. Or you could 720 (dp units) for minimum wide screen of 10'' screens.

Please, take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest) to get more details about `android:requiresSmallestWithDp`

Comment: If i add android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" then should i be able to install this app at phones too ?

Comment: from developer.android.com: Caution: The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute, so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime. Instead, it is used to enable filtering for your application on services such as Google Play. However, Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens.

Comment: Yes! But you must be sure you have all the necessary resources to allow that. You must Have drawable-sw600-xhdpi, drawable-sw600-hdpi, etc and layout-sw600 for tablet and the default ones for smartphones. If you only have `drawable-xhdpi` and `layout` then they will be used instead for smartphones and tablets but probably with bad scaling. Mae sure you have images with the desirable size to all size of devices.