# Your APK does not seem to be designed for tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, tablet

I am trying to upload one application to PlayStore and I get this warning : "Your APK does not seem to be designed for tablets"

The "Show Fix" hint tells me that "Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets"

This is how my manifest file looks like:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.mapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Can you please give me some hints ?

Comment: Check this out. Similar Question. Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854291/my-application-is-not-listed-for-tablets

Comment: yes, thanks. I saw it earlier today. this guys is missing the user-feature tags, which I have added :)

Comment: Still not working for you?

Comment: it does not. I mean, my manifest it is exactly as I put it in the post. Including uses-features and everything. :( Same message from Google

Comment: As far as i can tell it is just an optimization tip and it doesnt affect your app on the play store. So it will work perfectly on tablets and phones.

Comment: As user2511882 said, it seems that it worked. After publishing, the hint was gone (How strange is that). Thanks a lot

Comment: Great.I shall move this to an answer so you can accept and upvote it if you want. Cheers.!

Comment: u got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive however I think it relates to the phone values

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

and possibly the GPS values

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

If your app requires the phone then it definitely isn't designed for tablets (which don't have the phone antennas).  I'm doubtful the GPS is the problem since some tablets do have GPS antennas.

Comment: That is a decent comment. But accordingly to google docs here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#hardware-requirements , they say I need to add user-feature for each user permission that might not be available on tablet. Which I did, and based on the book, i should have no problems with that. That is why I added the required=false option

Comment: Oops, you're right.  My mind read that was true.  I have fixed the post

Comment: To be honest, it drives me nuts, I do not know what else to do. They (Google) are not giving specific hints at all... but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I agree they should give you more specific reasons.  Anyways, no worries.  If I think of something later I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell it is just an optimization tip and it doesnt affect your app on the play store. So it will work perfectly on tablets and phones