# Recover phone call UI

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

Basically I'd like to start the current phone call ui from a button in one of my `activities`.

So far, I've been able to start a new call using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:000000"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

or to move to the phonebook using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've also tried to use that code, but it seems not to be working on HTC devices and some Huawei (`ri` is `null`).

```
Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentToResolve.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intentToResolve.setPackage("com.android.phone");
ResolveInfo ri = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intentToResolve, 0);
if (ri != null) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentToResolve);
    intent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What I'd like to get is move directly to the call ui. The behaviour is the same as in this procedure:

1. Be in a phone call
2. Go back to the Home screen
3. Expand the notification bar
4. Click on the call row

I don't know how to achievve and how to make it works on all devices.

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do as suggested on this answer: [android.permission.CALL_PHONE for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882955/android-permission-call-phone-for-tablets)

add the call phone permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

and then call with `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.

```
Intent intentcall = new Intent(
          Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
          Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber));
startActivity(intentcall);
```

**edit:**

there's a way you could do, but it won't work in Lollipop and forward, as it's been deprecated due to security reasons.

You could use the `ActivityManager` to [get the running tasks](http://public%20List%3CActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo%3E%20getRunningTasks%20(int%20maxNum)) and then analyse the content of [each RunningTaskInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html) to determine which one is the "phone" and then use the [task ID to call moveTaskToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#moveTaskToFront(int,%20int)). It possibly work, but as I said, it will not work with Lollipop and future versions.

Comment: The intention of the question is not to place a call, but to return to the in-call screen of one *already in progress*.  Will this work for that?

Comment: oh... I'm very sorry, I understood it wrong. I will not work then.

Comment: take a look on my edit. Not a great answer, but just throwing some ideas.

Comment: Hello,it seems to work on old devices such as LG L5, but when I move to Samsung ACE 4 or S4, or event LG L65, I got an issue. Running `moveTaskToFront` on `com.android.phone id` doesn't work and throws a warning: `Task to front request from 10112 stopped`. Any idea why it doesn't work ? (Permissions look to be ok).

Comment: Sorry, i'm testing it on android `4.02` and `4.4.2`. No lollipop at all.

Comment: don't know then. That was a "best guess" approach.