# My android application not compatible with tablet

Tags: android

I am using a Samsung Tab A (SM-T550) tablet running Android 5.0.2. I am able to side-load the APK for my app successfully, but I'm not able to find the app in the Google Play Store. When I go to the Google Play Store link directly, Google Play claims that the app isn't compatible with my device.

Here what I added in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Build.gradle:

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

Permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

But same thing, my tablet not compatible.

When I install the APK directly, working perfectly.

Comment: My tablet is Samsung Tab A (SM-T550).

Comment: Running Android 5.0?

Comment: Running Android 5.0.2

Comment: How were you trying to install it when you got the error?

Comment: The error is when i try to find the application on Google Play, it do not appear, when i go directly to the google play link, my device is not compatible.

Comment: I assume that the minimum version allows Android 5?

Comment: How to know that ?

Comment: It should be listed in the manifest.

Comment: No it is not listed there, sorry.

Comment: But you can check my build.gradle two line i posted.

Comment: Why do you have these atributes in the manifest? Normally are not required. Please check the documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html Remove it from manifest and try again.

Comment: I'm curious - what happens if you try some of the things in this article? http://www.traemcneely.com/2011/12/17/how-to-fix-your-device-is-not-compatible-with-this-item-in-android-app-market/

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException i uploaded my application without theses line first time, and i found that my app not compatible with tablet, and today added this lines in case i solve the problem, any other solution ?

Comment: Try install it using ADB from Android Studio, maybe you got an error.

Comment: Working fine locally, apk install well, i have problem of incompatibility on google play only.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11692522/2294985

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin I was going to ask the same thing, actually - it does seem slightly odd that side-loading would work, though. I've never actually tried that though.

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin but my application need the camera ! and my tablet have a camera.

Comment: Are there any other hardware permissions you list in the manifest? What happens if you clear the Marketplace cache like the linked article suggests?

Comment: I didn't ran into this issue before, But did you tried to add <use-feature /> statement ?

Comment: I listed all the permissions of my manifest file. check the post.

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin yes i did that for camera.

Comment: Did you tried to add this to the manifest ' <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />'

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin i didn't, i will keep a try now.

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin I just saw that you suggested this - I just added it as an answer, I guess you beat me to it - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882955/android-permission-call-phone-for-tablets) says that that can cause the problem.

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin You was right, you solved the problem ! do you want create a comment to check your answer or i check the one of EJoshuaS ?

Comment: @JisMaxi He has more reputation than me so I guess I will create my own answer ^_^

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin Okey sir, waiting for it :).

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin You did suggest it slightly ahead of me anyway :)

Comment: That is why I gave you Vote up for your answer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Tablets need to add one more line of code,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

This was mainly for tablets with no sim cards, But I searched for the tablet you are using and it already has a sim card, More Info will be written in case I found the reason.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. My Tablet do not have a SIM CARD, purhapse some other model, but this one not.

Comment: Isn't this your model , http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_a_9_7-7122.php, It says here it has micro sim card

Comment: Me is SM-T550 :) is this one: http://www.samsung.com/levant/smartphones/galaxy-tab-a-9-7-t550/SM-T550NZWAMID/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882955/android-permission-call-phone-for-tablets), this can cause the app to be unavailable on the marketplace for tablets (since tablets can't be called). They recommend adding the following line to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

create layout folder name with `layout-sw320dp`, `layout-360dp`,`layout-sw480dp`, `layout-sw600dp` & `layout-sw800dp`.
Create All Layout which you need to show in Tablet Devices, make as per Tab size & put into appropriate Layout Folder.

No Need to Add `<supports-screens>` & `<compatible-screens>` code in `Manifest.xml`

Comment: Layout are same for all phones and tablet, i will duplicate the folder layout to layout-sw400dp, layout-sw320dp and layout-320dp?

Comment: Yes, But you need to modify size of widget as per device size.

Comment: Where and how to do that ?

Comment: Please create duplicate files of all layout files & put into `layout-sw600dp` & `layout-sw800dp` layout folder for 7 inch & 10 inch devices.

Comment: This won't work - the actual problem is the fact that he requests Call permission and tablets can't accept calls.