# PlayStore App Not Showing in Android Tablet

Tags: android, tablet, android-permissions, google-play

my application is available on playstore. when i search the my application in tablet, it is not showing app list. in playstore optimation tips showing "**Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets**"

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false"/>

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"  android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: try by searching with package name of your app.

Comment: i think you have to add this feature :<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/> to your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

There is no `android:required` attribute for `<uses-permission>`. Hence, remove those, as they are doing you no good.

Then, you will want to review [the list of permissions that imply feature requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) and make adjustments to your `<uses-feature>` elements as desired.

For example, by requesting the `CALL_PHONE` permission, you are indicating that the device *has* to have telephony capability. If you do not want that, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>` to your roster of `<uses-feature>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Some permissions in your manifest may act as filters that filter search results in play store. eg: CALL_PHONE, READ_PHONE_STATE etc.

Please modify your manifest file as following:

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
> ```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

Also you need to programatically check for hardwares and must avoid crash in devices that does not have that hardware.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Instead of the `CALL_PHONE` permission add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Take a look at this related question:

[can't find app on market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573413/cant-find-app-on-market)

Once check your permissions you specified in manifest.If the device doesn't support one of these (doesn't have a simcard, doesn't support GPS,WiFi etc), then you probably can't find it.

Comment: i mean both are need or not <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" /> permmision

Comment: asking CALL_PHONE featue   06-14 16:38:01.195: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{40b82318 6090:com.webappclouds.salondebonair/10111} (pid=6090, uid=10111) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Comment: Once check your permissions you specified in manifest.If the device doesn't support one of these (doesn't have a simcard, doesn't support GPS,WiFi etc), then you probably can't find it.

Comment: but i want without simcard, need to show app in the playstore list

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all `<uses-permission...>` that you don't need.